# How i get DISTINCT values in minim row? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table Orders_Header, Order_Sequence, Orders_Samples with value.I want to get unique value from 3 tables:

I have one row in Orders_Header:

[image]

I have 2 rows in Orders_Sequence:
[image]

I have 4 rows in Orders_Samples:

[image]

My Sql Code are that:

```
SELECT orders_header.plant, 
       orders_header.shortyear, 
       orders_header.orderno, 
       orders_header.orderdate, 
       orders_header.closingdate, 
       orders_header.requester, 
       orders_header.projectnumber, 
       orders_header.costcenter, 
       orders_header.batchnumber, 
       orders_header.partname, 
       orders_header.partnumber, 
       orders_header.costcategory, 
       orders_header.status, 
       orders_header.overallproductrating, 
       orders_sequence.activitynumber, 
       orders_sequence.dimension, 
       orders_sequence.description, 
       orders_sequence.activityname, 
       orders_sequence.activityresource, 
       orders_sequence.requirementnom, 
       orders_sequence.requirementplus, 
       orders_sequence.requirementminus, 
       orders_sequence.units, 
       orders_samples.samplenumber, 
       orders_samples.samplevalue 
FROM   orders_header 
       INNER JOIN orders_sequence 
               ON orders_header.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
       INNER JOIN orders_samples 
               ON orders_samples.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
WHERE  ( orders_header.orderno = 79148 ) 
       AND ( orders_header.shortyear = 16 )
```

Why i get 8 rows istead of 4, i want unique rows. I have 4 rows in Orders_Samples i want in final 4 rows with all dates.

I try with distinct but doesn't work

NOTE* I try with DISTINCT but doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: Are the 8 rows duplicated in any way? (like 4 sets of 2) If nothing joins or coalesces samples and sequence, then you are probably getting (1x2x4).

Comment: What is the output of the query supposed to be explaining? Something like "Here is the last sample and sequence for this order?"

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select orders_header.plant, ...

FROM   orders_header

inner join (select distinct orderid from orders_sequence) ord_sequence
on orders_header.orderid = ord_sequence.orderid 
inner join orders_samples ON orders_samples.orderid = ord_sequence.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT orders_header.plant, 
   orders_header.shortyear, 
   orders_header.orderno, 
   orders_header.orderdate, 
   orders_header.closingdate, 
   orders_header.requester, 
   orders_header.projectnumber, 
   orders_header.costcenter, 
   orders_header.batchnumber, 
   orders_header.partname, 
   orders_header.partnumber, 
   orders_header.costcategory, 
   orders_header.status, 
   orders_header.overallproductrating, 
   orders_sequence.activitynumber, 
   orders_sequence.dimension, 
   orders_sequence.description, 
   orders_sequence.activityname, 
   orders_sequence.activityresource, 
   orders_sequence.requirementnom, 
   orders_sequence.requirementplus, 
   orders_sequence.requirementminus, 
   orders_sequence.units, 
   orders_samples.samplenumber, 
   orders_samples.samplevalue 
FROM   orders_samples
   LEFT JOIN orders_sequence 
           ON orders_samples.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
   LEFT JOIN orders_header  
           ON orders_header.orderid = orders_sequence.orderid 
WHERE  ( orders_header.orderno = 79148 ) 
   AND ( orders_header.shortyear = 16 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with this minimum query and add fields until you find the one causing the duplication.

```
SELECT
  oh.order_id 
  osam.samplenumber, 
  osam.samplevalue,
  oseq.activitynumber
FROM orders_samples osam
  INNER JOIN orders_header oh
    ON osam.order_id = oh.order_id
  LEFT JOIN orders_sequence oseq
    ON oh.order_id = oseq.order_id
WHERE  ( oh.orderno = 79148 ) 
 AND ( oh.shortyear = 16 )
```

Comment: Nop, the same, i give 8 rows